# How to update data in pptx file in python

Tags: python-pptx

Update data pptx file in python using python-pptx lib
If anybody have code please share

from pptx import Presentation

## import Image

prs = Presentation('SamplePowerpoint.pptx')
try:
from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
import Image

Answer (score 0):

use xlswriter library in python, use link below to know in details
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

using this you can insert anything like images, graphs, charts, table data etc, its very easy and straight forward.

Comment: Ok I will try Thanks for reply @DirtyHand